# How to import texture maps from Poser to Blender?

Tags: texturing, import

How to import texture maps from Poser to Blender?

The texture maps for props won't import to Blender. I've tried exporting FBX files.

Does anybody have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago the "blender3dclub" started a Poser prop/character importer module for Blender 2.6x. I dusted [that project off and ported it to Blender 2.8x](https://github.com/jentron/Blender-PT2), and started making some improvements. It now loads props (PP2/PPZ) and (CR2/CRZ) files and supports morphs (a.k.a. shape keys) for both props and characters, and loads the armature for characters. It currently doesn't automatically add the armature modifier.

Materials and textures, unfortunately for your question, don't work very well at this point. The plugin is still very much a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 0):

Blender fbx importer is a bit rudimentary. Neither the exporter nor the importer supports nested textures. So you will have to find a way in Poser to export the maps manually.
The import option has a checkmark "Image Search" which is on by default. If your images are labeled correctly, it should be able to assign them to the according channels. If not you will need to do that manually.